# Wso2 Apimanager jaggeryapps

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have security vulnerabilities in `jaggery` apps in wso2am 1.7.0 
What are `.jag` files in `jaggeryapps` in `<am_home>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/..` in wso2 `apimanager` ? and how to come over it.

Answer (score 1):

APIM store and publisher are written in [Jaggery.js](http://jaggeryjs.org/). There were known security issues in them, and you can find security patches from [here](http://wso2.com/security-patch-releases/#api-manager).